# Django get parameter from url in Template to set CSS

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dynamic category menu list in my template that I would like to highlight (set active) when the url parameter matches the menu item. Therefore when the page equals the menu item the category will be highlighted.

URL examples:

https://[domainname]/training/?category=1

https://[domainname]/training/?category=2

https://[domainname]/training/?category=3

```
{% for categories in category_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'training' %}?category={{categories.Category_id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if request.GET.category == 'categories.Category_id' %}active{% endif %}">
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your if block before displaying the ***a*** tag, add ***active*** class only when your *if* condition is fulfilled, like that:

```
{% for categories in category_list %}
 
   {% if request.GET.category == 'categories.Category_id' %}
<a href="{% url 'training' %}?category={{categories.Category_id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
  
  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'training' %}?category={{categories.Category_id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">
 {% endif %}

{% endfor%}
```

Just verify the condition if it's really select the case you want or not.

Comment: Your logic makes prefect sense however is its still not working. Is it possible that the URL parameter is a character comparing a integer? Or is 1=1 and 2=2 always equal in this scenario.

Comment: My problem was that I was comparing a string to an integer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I think you should overcome it either just by getting red of the ' 'like : ` {% if request.GET.category == categories.Category_id %}` , no ?